# В каком редакторе лучше визуализировать реляционную базу данных с отношениями?

Tags: mysql, поиск-программ

Надо сделать схему базы данных для показа ее руководству. Структуру таблиц и связей я разработал, но ее нужно как то красиво отобразить. Нужно отобразить таблицы с названиями и типами полей, ключами, отношениями между таблицами (один к одному, один ко многим). Чтобы это выглядело красиво. Так то можно и в дизайнере phpMyAdmina сделать, но что то уж очень не красиво там. Можно в ворде просто нарисовать, но может есть специализированный удобный инструмент?

Comment: dbeaver может ...